# Href is not working on Edge or IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have this code,

```
<li class="centro-de-servicios col-md-3 col-xs-12 dropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon-centro-de-servicios"></i>
        Service Center            <i class="arrow-down"></i>
        <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=centro-de-servicios" page="centro-de-servicios">Start</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=sobre-nosotros" page="sobre-nosotros">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=nuestras-politicas" page="nuestras-politicas">Our Policies</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=mantenimiento" page="mantenimiento">Maintenance</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=cotizar-visita" page="cotizar-visita">Quote a Visit</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=boletas" page="boletas">Service Tickets</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="?page=centro-de-servicios&section=intercambio" page="intercambio"></a></li>-->
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=consejos" page="consejos">Advice</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=contacto" page="contacto">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
```

When i'm positioned on any element, and try to go to another page, the page is just refreshing, not changing. This happens only on Edge and IE.

I tried "window.location.href = 'url'", "location.href = 'url'", "location= 'url'", "location.replace('url')", etc, and there are not working, if a put a target blank it works, but i don't want the target blank.

Comment: Show us what the actual HTML output looks like (instead of PHP code no one here will be able to reproduce your result with.) Please go read up on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I update to the actual HTML output

Comment: show some javascript code that you use. location = '"http:// example.com"' works fine in IE

Comment: `<li onclick="location = 'http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=centro-de-servicios" page="centro-de-servicios'"><a href="javascript:void(8)">Start</a></li>`

Comment: Can we consider http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&section=centro-de-servicios a live example of the problem? If so, when I am on that page and then click the link “Nuestras Politicas” from the dropdown menu, in IE11 dev tools network panel, I see it try to make the request for `/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&amp;section=nuestras-politicas` for a fraction of a second – and then the request status changes to “aborted”, and it requests the current URL again. Do you have any JavaScript event handlers on those menu links that might interfere …?

Comment: Yes, that url is a live example. No, I don't have any event handler interfering with that, actually in another browser works fine.

Comment: @CBroe see my answer... any idea about that click handler? Seems flawed

Comment: @yezzz: Yeah, that looks as if it might as well the the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the url and put extra page="" in it.

Try it like this:

```
<li onclick = "location = 'http://beta.capris.cr/servicios/?page=centro-de-servicios&section=centro-de‌​-servicios'"><a href="javascript:void(8)">Start</a></li>
```

EDIT:
Have a look at this code on your page:

```
        jQuery(".submenu a").click(function () {
             jQuery(location).attr(jQuery(this).attr("href"));
             location.reload();
//            setTimeout(function () {
//                updatePage(currentPage, location.hash);
//            }, 10);
        });
```

Comment: I see you gave wrong code sample. Real issue is something else. I do see there's a click handler

Comment: see my edit... what's the function of that click handler?

Comment: @rleiva: This line `jQuery(location).attr(jQuery(this).attr("href"));` hardly makes any sense at all, and this piece of code is likely the cause of your problem in IE. Trying to modify the location fails, and so `location.reload()` just reloads the current page. Just remove that event handler altogether, and let the href attribute of the links do their work.

Comment: IE console wasn't even showing that handler... found it via firebug... go figure